# python (and AWS): having trouble sorting list of S3 keys by date

Tags: python, sorting

I have the following block of python code

```
b = c.get_bucket(bucket)
lst = []
for prfx in prefix_list:
    for f in b.list(prefix=prfx):
        lst.append(f)
sorted(lst, key=lambda kk: kk.last_modified, reverse=True)
```

Basically, I create a list of AWS S3 keys (`lst`) from another list of prefixes (`prefix_list`) and then try to sort this list by the last modification date of the keys. I am probably making some basic Python error here, 'cuz `lst` does not get sorted. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure to grab the return value. sorted() returns a new list, it doesn't modify the existing one in place.

```
lst = sorted(lst, key=lambda kk: kk.last_modified, reverse=True)
```

Comment: Alternatively, you could use `lst.sort(key=...` to do the sorting in place.

Comment: @John: yes, indeed a basic mistake as I suspected :-)